# PHP breaks string when bigger than 2^16

Tags: php, macos, buffer-overflow

I'm currently struggling with a weird behaviour of PHP (at least it seems weird to me).

I've got this code (it matches all `src` and `href` attributes inside a buffered HTML page, which may be not yet optimal, but works flawlessly):

```
$regex = '#(</?\w+\s+(?:\w+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^"\'>\s]+))?\s*)*(?:href|src)\s*=\s*)("[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^"\'>\s]+)#Uis';
$buffer = preg_replace_callback($regex, function($match) {
    $match[2] = preg_replace('/^["\'](.*)["\']$/', '\1', $match[2]);
    // do further stuff
    return $match[0];
}, $buffer);
```

Now, it took me *very* long to figure out why `preg_replace_callback` will return NULL in only *some* situations, and it turned out, that it breaks when the string is bigger than 2^16, which seems weird to me, because I never had any limitation problems with PHP before and I even buffered files of several hundreds of MB.

What I tried now is this:

```
$test = str_repeat('1', 65537); // 2**16+1
echo $test; // NULL (prints an empty string)
```

I asked Google, but I really found **nothing**. There seems to be no one having this problem, and every source says you can even store GB in a string.

I'm using OS X and the built-in AMPP environment.

Comment: What is your `display_errors` setting? Do you see anything in the error log?

Comment: I have error handler functions to log all errors in a custom file and bypass the displaying of errors. However, even when I turn them off and set `display_errors` to `On` (which is default in my `php.ini`), there's still no PHP error. It just does nothing with the string.

Comment: What is the memory limit (`memory_limit` in php.ini)? Strings should be able to get as big as 2GB, if the configuration allows this much memory to be allocated.

Comment: `memory_limit` is set to `128M`.